# Android AudioRecorder stop recording when no input

Tags: android, audio-recording

Ok my question is the following:

1. I want to get the smartphone microphone input
2. When the user stops talking, it should automatically stop recording (like the google voice search does)

How can I achieve that? Any idea?

Comment: Do some signal power calculation on the PCM data that you get from `AudioRecord` (RMS, for example) and stop recording when the value goes below a threshold of your choise.

Comment: Ok. I will check that.